# htaccess regex redirect puts "HTTP/1.0" in url

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have this regex in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*?/out/([^/]+)/?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com/%2?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

This url

```
www.mydomain.com/out/cars/bmw/
```

returns

```
http://cars.example.com/bmw/%20HTTP/1.0?aid=123
```

In fact, there is always **%20HTTP/1.0** before **?aid=123** no matter what URL with **www.mydomain.com/out/** I try :(

Why? How to get rid of it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please read more about regex use in htaccess files. You might want to refer to the documentation of your webserver (nginx, apache, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is matching on THE_REQUEST which has more than you think in it. Use REQUEST_URI instead. Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /out/([^/]+)/?(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.example.com/%2?aid=123 [NE,L,R=302]
```

For reference:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Comment: Thank you so much!